# Написать програму для решения следующей задачи используя рекурсию

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, рекурсия

Нужно написать рекурсивную функцию, которая получает массив символов и проверяет содержит ли он правильную запись идентификатора. Идентификатор - это имя переменной. И покажите что здесь не так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
 
int recFoo(char arr[],const int size,int i)
{
    if(arr[i]='\0')
    {
        cout <<"Identifier is correct."<<endl;
        return true;
    }
    if(!isalpha(arr[0]) && arr[0]!='_')
    {
        cerr<<"Wrong identifier!!!";
        return false;
    }
    
    if(isalpha(arr[i])||isdigit(arr[i])||arr[i]=='_')
    {
        return recFoo(arr,size,i++);
    }
    else
    {
        cerr<<"Wrong identifier!!!";
        return false;
    }
    
}
 
int main()
{
    const int size=20;
    char arr[size];
    int i=1;
    
    cout <<"Input some identifier: ";
    cin >>arr;
    cout <<endl;
    
    recFoo(arr,size,i);
    
}
```

Comment: что значит "покажите что здесь не так"?

Comment: а здесь что-то не так?

Answer (score 3):

```
if(arr[i]='\0')
{
    cout <<"Identifier is correct."<<endl;
    return true;
}
```

Этот фрагмент никогда не выполнится - вы просто зануляете в нем `a[i]`; и получаете `if (false)...` Понятно, что дальше ничего не работает. Но если бы работало, то...

Далее, проверка

```
if(!isalpha(arr[0]) && arr[0]!='_')
```

корректна, но зачем ее повторять при обработке каждого символа?

И совершенно непонятно, зачем передавать `size` в качестве аргумента.

Это то, что бросилось в глаза мне...

Answer (score 2):

Не очень понятно что вам нужно, но в строке:

```
if(arr[i]='\0')
...
```

вы присваиваете элементу массива новое значение. Для проверки на равенство необходимо использовать оператор `==` :

```
 if(arr[i] == '\0')
...
```